# Add linkedIn and Twitter in Application

Tags: iphone

I need to add Twitter and LinkedIn in my application. Bith Twitter and LinkedIn use oAuth files so i cannot able to add then only can add one of them. when i try to use Same files for both then only linkedIn work and get error "The token is expire" for twitter.

can any one know how to add both in same application.

Comment: In following link their is a tutorial for the integration of the twitter and also set the linkedIn that program in that i integrate the shrekit into the project i it is easy to instal and integrate so this helping to you, [Reference link is Here.](http://bit.ly/IOwVeX)

Comment: With [ShareKit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) you can easily support sharing to both destinations (also Facebook, Foursquare... even more). Official tutorial is [here](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit).

Comment: @neonsamuel...thanks for your reply...but linkedIn is not working in ur example code.After authorization it shows web page with text "authorization successfull", not redirect to any view to post text msg.